# Three JS, add specularity (shine) to texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a texture I am applying to an object in three.js. I want to add some specularity or shininess to it.

I see examples that look like this

```
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
    color: 0x996633, 
    specular: 0x050505,
    shininess: 100
} );
```

However, my code looks like this:

```
// texture
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var imgLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
imgLoader.load( 'assets/uv.png', function ( image ) {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
} );

// model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'assets/obj.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            child.material.map = texture;
        }
    } );
    object.position.y = - 95;
    scene.add( object );
}, onProgress, onError );
```

I am not sure where to add the shininess or specular setting since I'm not using a `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`, or if I did use the `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`, how to combine it with `THREE.texture`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you override the object's material when it's loaded.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load('assets/obj.obj', function (object) {
    object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                color:     0x996633, 
                specular:  0x050505,
                shininess: 100,
                map:       texture,
                side:      THREE.DoubleSide
            });
        }
    } );
    object.position.y = - 95;
    scene.add(object);
}, onProgress, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

three.js provides quite a lot of materials that all behave differently and use different properties to be configured (see [these examples here](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=variations) to get an overview). If you want to get a glossy look, you will probably go for either [`MeshStandardMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshStandardMaterial) or [`MeshPhongMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshPhongMaterial). The ducomentation will also tell you the properties available to configure the materials.

`MeshStandardMaterial` is something like a newer version of the phong-material. It's the more "correct" (physically speaking) and more computationally expensive option while the MeshPhongMaterial is a good approximation.

The piece of Information you are probably missing is that you can just replace materials as you like, so in your example that would be something like

```
if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
    var oldMaterial = child.material;
    child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        map: texture
        // ..if neccesary, copy properties like color from oldMaterial
    });
}
```

to completely replace the material.