# Material renders unnaturally (glossy)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to render an object with materials using Three.js, but it looks differently than in other online viewers like https://3dviewer.net (also uses Three.js under the hood)

I tried to rise level of details (LOD) and also used NearestFilter / LinearFilter but without any effect.

This is [how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a9rU.png) (screenshot of rendered by 3dviewer object) .

And this is [how it looks in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia9G5.png)

In 3dviewer version it looks more natural, and in my it is too shiny and glossy

Should I apply some specific filter (though did not find it in 3dviewer sources) or may be lighting?

My current code is:

```
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( '#edeff2' );

let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100,   window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 100;

let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;

let keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

let fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

let backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

scene.add(keyLight);
scene.add(fillLight);
scene.add(backLight);

let mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setTexturePath('/examples/3d-obj-loader/assets/');
mtlLoader.setPath('/examples/3d-obj-loader/assets/');
mtlLoader.load('b.mtl', function (materials) {

materials.preload();

let objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
objLoader.setPath('/examples/3d-obj-loader/assets/');
objLoader.load('b.obj', function (object) {

    scene.add(object);
    object.position.y -= 100;

    object.scale.x = 0.01;
    object.scale.y = 0.01;
    object.scale.z = 0.01;

    let boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object)
    let size = boundingBox.getSize()
});
});

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

Link to object, materials + textures - [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtyqtqz2eopp9ld/three.zip?dl=0)

Comment: please add some code so that it becomes clear what is the problem

Comment: @TowkirAhmed sure, just updated the question

Comment: also need to see the mtl file

Comment: @gaitat sure, attached to the question - https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtyqtqz2eopp9ld/three.zip?dl=0 it is a zip with obj, mtl and textures

Comment: I see the specular exponent `Ns` to be high

Comment: @gaitat thanks for the hint! But I can't adjust materials or objects, they're coming from 3rd party services. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990102/1980846

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the materials of your object.

```
objLoader.load('b.obj', function (object) {
    // Access material
    var mat = object.material;

    // Make material less shiny
    mat.metalness = 0;
    mat.roughness = 1;

    scene.add(object);
    object.position.y -= 100;

    object.scale.x = 0.01;
    object.scale.y = 0.01;
    object.scale.z = 0.01;

    let boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object)
    let size = boundingBox.getSize()
});
```

How you access the material depends on the structure of your `object`. It could be `object.children[0].material`, or `object.children[0].children[0].material`, depending on how it's nested.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and I had to apply a filter to all of my materials:

```
function getAllMaterials( object ) {
 var out = [];
 object.traverse( function( node ) {
  if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { out.push( node.material ) }
 } );
 return out;
}

getAllMaterials( <your-3D-Object-Here> ).forEach( function ( mat ) {
 if ( Array.isArray( mat ) ) {
  mat.forEach( function( cmat ) { cmat.shininess /= 19; } )
 }
 else { mat.shininess /= 19 }
} );
```

You might need to change that static 19 in the code to whatever fits your needs. If you have any questions, I'll set up live example for you.